# FabricJS export relative to canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm building a authoring tool in FabricJS which is meant to export something for android devices. It's decided that I will support only 6/9 screen ratio (other screens will get black borders).
My problem is that I open the page on my pc, add and edit some elements and export ( using the fabricjs serializer ) and then I open on a laptop (different display size), the canvas gets resized correctly (with some js magic) but the elements are still at the same location and same size as on the big display
.
The problem is that FabricJS does not create elements relative to canvas size.

I can write my own export/load functions, but it feels wrong because each element has *width*, *height*, *scaleX* and *scaleY*. Using the handles changes the scale for some reason. This leads me to think that there is something like a canvas scale, but there is not.

Am I missing something? How does one go about exporting and then opening on a different screen, but maintaining the canvas ratio and having elements relative to the canvas size.

Comment: How are you resizing the Canvas object? Using CSS ?
Any sample JsBin?

Comment: @DarrylHebbes I am using fabric's canvas.setWidth() and canvas.setHeight() to set the dimmensions as the container's dimmensions. (the canvas is contained in a div which is 60% of the window width, so the container scales with the width. Same for the height)